# Help understanding/reading RF data from an ad8362 sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, gps, rf, analog

It's my first time posting so I apologize if anything is wrong or missing.

I'm doing a project where I'm trying to combine EMF/RF readings with GPS data to create a heat map of exposure levels in an area. Right now I'm trying to make sense/properly read data from [this](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832814998589.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt) sensor, and so far I have hooked it up to my arduino uno r3 analog and 5V pins.

I've been able to get an output, but from what I can tell it isn't anything viable or usable as it seems to be dependent on the connection rather than the location of the "antenna".

Using code to simply read out the analog pin:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

}
 
void loop() {
   Serial.println(analogRead(0));
   delay(1500);
}
```

This is the readout:
[Seems random to me, when there is no input 'antenna' the value holds at 2 or 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8dxo.png)

Here is my crude setup to try and figure the sensor out (I have proper SMA connectors to use in the future):[image]

I understand that I likely won't be getting an answer or a step by step, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction or give some advice. I have been trying to figure things out but information is limited, and I am unfortunately not super well versed in small electronics or coding, and need some help finding my way. All assuming this idea is even possible... :)

I should note that precision or units arent super necessary for me, I just need to have a reading that I know is an RF value and that is ballpark.

Open to any questions or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: start by reading the datasheet for the sensor ... determine what output the sensor produces and how the output relates to the received signal ... use an oscilloscope instead of an Arduino

Comment: The problem you are facing has nothing to do with code, and therefore nothing to do with Arduino. It is the understand of how the chip work and about RF signalling. The datasheet shown that the output is relatively linear for producing an output voltage between somewhat 0.2v for an input signal at -55dbm to about 3.5v at 10dbm across a wide range of spectrum. You are expecting the dupoint wire at the input would produce an RF signal strong enough for -55dbm with an input impedance matching 50-ohm, unfortunately it doesn't work that way for Radio signal.